# Query Char varying postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, char, varying

I've been trying to make the following query works, but I couldn't:

```
   SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (users.roles LIKE "%sales%")
or
   SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (users.roles LIKE '%sales%')
```

where roles, can contain:

```
 {operations,business_development,sales,customer_service,manager}
```

and roles is: `character varying[]`

I'm getting the error:

> ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying[] ~~ unknown LINE
>   1: select users.id from users where  users.roles LIKE '%sales%'...

Comment: `SELECT * FROM users  WHERE roles LIKE '%sales%'` - This should work, I guess.

Comment: @Thilo I tried both for sure, neither " or ' is working

Comment: character varying[] , as the question title says :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE  'sales' = ANY(users.roles)
```

Having said that, it's worth noting:

> Tip: Arrays are not sets; searching for specific array elements can be
>   a sign of database misdesign. Consider using a separate table with a
>   row for each item that would be an array element. This will be easier
>   to search, and is likely to scale better for a large number of
>   elements.

[http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/arrays.html](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html)

Comment: `any` function can not be used as a left argument as I remember.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it actually but in the wrong way. ` users.roles = ANY('sales')`. I'm not used to this syntax